# query_post returns all posts even if I specify a specific value for a taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a simple `query_posts` using a custom post type and a taxonomy linked to it. I use the plugin [MAGIC FIELD](http://magicfields.org/) to achieve my goal.

Here is the code.

```
<?php
    // Display the persons with Sport Injuries Speciality //
      wp_reset_query();

      // Args
      $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'physician',
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'orderby' => 'menu_order',
          'type_of_speciality' => 'Sport Medecine specialist'
          );

      // The Query
      query_posts( $args );

      // The Loop
      while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      result here
      endwhile;
      wp_reset_query();
 ?>
```

As you can see, I want to display only the posts with 'Sport Medecine specialist' as there speciality. The admin has to check a Radio button.

Is there something I'm missing because I should only have 3 results and it gives me all the posts for this custom post type.

**EDIT #1:**

I have made a little work around, but this is not really good for speed optimization since it loop in all the custom post types.

```
 <?php
    // Display the persons with Sport Injuries Speciality //
      wp_reset_query();

      // Args
      $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'physician',
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'orderby' => 'menu_order',
          );

      // The Query
      query_posts( $args );

      // The Loop
      while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      if(get('type_of_speciality') == 'Sport Medecine specialist')
      { 
         echo the_title();
      }
      endwhile;
      wp_reset_query();
?>
```

As you can see, the `if()` condition check if the "taxonomy" has Sport Medecine specialist as value and `exit(else)` if the value do not match.

Like I said, it is not very good because if I would have 1000 physicians, it would loop trought the 1000's.

Any idea to light me up?

Comment: type_of_speciality is a taxonomy, right?

Comment: Don't use `query_posts`. Like in never use it

Comment: @PieterGoosen can you link a page where they explain why I should never use it again?

Comment: Read [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) in the codex, and this is my emphasis as well

Answer (score 1):

Change the way you're querying it, instead of tax => value, use tax_query and instead of using `query_posts()` use `WP_Query`

See if it works for you.

[WP_Query taxonomy parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'physician',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type_of_speciality',
            'field'    => 'slug',   //term_id or slug
            'terms'    => 'sport-medecine-specialist',  // the term ( id or slug ) based on the value of field above
        ),
    ),
);

$search = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $search->have_posts() ) : $search->the_post();

    the_title();

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I think this solution could work. But I would need to know this. Terms = the returned value? I just try to copy-paste and it showed nothing. We need to know that my type_of_speciality has been made with magic field plugin.

Comment: `terms` is equal to the slug of the term, in that example, I don't know what is the slug, you should put the right slug in there for the code to work or change the value for `field` to id and then in `terms` put the taxonomy id and then it should work.